# how to distinguish disparity image good or bad

Tags: python, image, opencv

[image: disparity image]

[image: left image]

[image: right image]
    import numpy as np
    from sklearn.preprocessing import normalize
    import cv2

```
print('loading images...')
imgL = cv2.imread("C:/Users/admin/jupyter/car/challenge_pictrue/right/right2.jpg ")
imgR = cv2.imread("C:/Users/admin/jupyter/car/challenge_pictrue/left/left2.jpg ")

# SGBM Parameters -----------------
window_size = 3                     # wsize default 3; 5; 7 for SGBM reduced size image; 15 for SGBM full size image (1300px and above); 5 Works nicely

left_matcher = cv2.StereoSGBM_create(
    minDisparity=0,
    numDisparities=160,             # max_disp has to be dividable by 16 f. E. HH 192, 256
    blockSize=5,
    P1=8 * 3 * window_size ** 2,    # wsize default 3; 5; 7 for SGBM reduced size image; 15 for SGBM full size image (1300px and above); 5 Works nicely
    P2=32 * 3 * window_size ** 2,
    disp12MaxDiff=1,
    uniquenessRatio=15,
    speckleWindowSize=0,
    speckleRange=2,
    preFilterCap=63,
    mode=cv2.STEREO_SGBM_MODE_SGBM_3WAY
)

right_matcher = cv2.ximgproc.createRightMatcher(left_matcher)

# FILTER Parameters
lmbda = 80000
sigma = 1.2
visual_multiplier = 1.0

wls_filter = cv2.ximgproc.createDisparityWLSFilter(matcher_left=left_matcher)
wls_filter.setLambda(lmbda)
wls_filter.setSigmaColor(sigma)

print('computing disparity...')
displ = left_matcher.compute(imgL, imgR)  # .astype(np.float32)/16
dispr = right_matcher.compute(imgR, imgL)  # .astype(np.float32)/16
displ = np.int16(displ)
dispr = np.int16(dispr)
filteredImg = wls_filter.filter(displ, imgL, None, dispr)  # important to put "imgL" here!!!

filteredImg = cv2.normalize(src=filteredImg, dst=filteredImg, beta=0, alpha=255, norm_type=cv2.NORM_MINMAX);
filteredImg = np.uint8(filteredImg)
cv2.imshow('Disparity Map', filteredImg)
cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I don't know how to Distinguish good or bad for this disparity image.
Can anybody help me to illustrate this disparity image?

Comment: Can you remove the WLS filter in the disparity map and attach again.  So actual disparity image can kept for reference.

Comment: Sorry, i don't know how to do remove the WLS filter in the disparity map. So i put the full code on question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve a good disparity map:

1. Your scene should have random texture.  If the scene is highly textured you will get good disparity map.

Bad disparity map:

1. When your calibration data goes wrong.  You should get your calibration data correct.
2. When your scene have repetitive patterns or un-textured  your disparity is map would have lost more data.  We cannot call it directly as bad map but its expected behavior.